# Saving user settings when exiting the app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My program has a settings menu that allows you to change the window resolution and font color. When you exit, these user settings must be saved and you don't have to change them when you restart the app.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
class App(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.root = Tk()
      self.master = self.root
      m = Menu(self.root)
      self.root.config(menu=m)
      cm = Menu(m)
      m.add_cascade(label="Color",menu=cm)
      cm.add_command(label="Default",command=self.colorD)
      cm.add_command(label="Red",command=self.colorR)
      cm.add_command(label="Green",command=self.colorG)
      cm.add_command(label="Blue",command=self.colorB)
      sm = Menu(m)
      m.add_cascade(label="Size",menu=sm)
      sm.add_command(label="500x500",command = 
              lambda:self.master.geometry('500x500'))
      sm.add_command(label="800x600",command = lambda: 
              self.master.geometry('800x600'))
      sm.add_command(label="1024x768",command = lambda: 
              self.master.geometry('1024x768'))
      self.txt = Text(self.root, font=('Arial',12))
      self.txt.pack()
  def colorD(self):
      self.txt.config(bg="white", fg="black")
  def colorR(self):  
      self.txt.config(bg="crimson", fg="yellow")
  def colorG(self):
      self.txt.config(bg="green", fg="blue")
  def colorB(self):
      self.txt.config(bg="skyblue", fg="dark violet")
  def on_execute(self):
      self.root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = App()
  app.on_execute()
```

Comment: Store the user's setting in variables like `self.bg` and `self.fg` then at the end just save them to a file. Next time you open the program read the file and call the appropriate function.

Comment: When I write variables in the file, they overwrite each other. Can you explain how to do it properly?

Comment: what do You mean they overwrite, just write every setting to the file when program stops, that way everything will be overwritten with everything. the reason they overwrite is because You use probably `w` which is write mode and it overwrites, You could use `a` append mode but it is better if You just write all settings to the file, so read them save to a variable, change or append to the variable and then write the whole variable back to file

Comment: @Matiiss Using append mode isn't the best idea because each time the user changes the settings the settings file will become larger. This means that the file can get quite big especially when there are a lot of settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of storing the user's settings:

```py
import pickle
settings = {"bg": "red", "fg": "blue"}

# Save the settings to the file
with open("filename", "wb") as file:
    file.write(pickle.dumps(settings))

# Open the settings from the file
with open("filename", "rb") as file:
    loaded_settings = pickle.loads(file.read())
```

It uses the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to save and load the settings dictionary.